# Maximizing log-likelihood function with python

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize, log-likelihood

i'm trying to maximize the log-likelihood function with python, using the funcion "minimize" from scipy.optimize.

declaring the log-likelihood function this way:

```
def like(mu,sigma,x):
l = -(len(x)/2)*np.log(2*np.pi) - (len(x)/2)*np.log(sigma)-(1/2*sigma)*np.dot((x-mu).T,(x-mu))
return -l
```

then trying to use "minimize" with method = "BFGS":

```
param = minimize(like,start_params,method="BFGS")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: like() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'sigma' and 'x'
```

Obviously i need to optimize w.r.t mu and sigma, given an x input vector.

Could somebody help with this ?

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate that x is required to be the first variable in your function. You have it as the third variable. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: It seems i needed to pack the parameters to be optimized into a vector:

par = mu, sigma

and then defining the function: like(par,x): mu,sigma=par ....

Thank you anyway